# Vk неправильно выводит информацию из meta og: тегов

Tags: html, вконтакте, оптимизация-сайтов, meta

Столкнулся проблемной, что vk при отправки ссылки главной страницы http://alisa-music.ru/ отображает не заданный `<meta property="og:title" content="Все песни Алисы Кожикиной">`, а Название из `<H2 itemprop="name">`с микроразметкой (который даже не первый встречающийся). Также и с дочерними ссылками сайта

Но [сайт проверки og тегов](https://opengraphcheck.com/result.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Falisa-music.ru#.XRNccugzaUk) показывает всё правильно.

Как я могу это исправить с минимальной правкой сайта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Проблема решается временем (3-5 дней)

Через несколько дней после установки тегов, все стало как должно.

[Вк кеширует данные и не обновляет информацию в течении пары дней](https://vk.com/dev/publications?f=3.%20%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA)
Принудительно отчистить кешь ссылки в ВК можно [здесь](https://vk.com/dev/pages.clearCache)

PS.У меня микроразметка была задана раньше Og-тегов на пару дней